# OData Client message creation hook when using Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: c#, odata, azure-cognitive-search

**NOTE**: Complete rewrite of original question to focus on defining the EDM model and message creation hook

See [custom DataServiceContext](https://gist.github.com/MatthewDavidCampbell/7f0433966742fb4ffd05a6f24a3df18b) (gist) where the EDM model is [explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/model-builder-untyped) created.  Index definitions from Azure Cognitive Search (from the REST API) have a JSON format which is neither in EDM XML or [CSDL syntax](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/87aac894a40640f89920d7b2a414499b.html?locale=en-US&version=7.52.0).  Would have expected a natural definition consumption by a Microsoft client from a Microsoft server service.  Is a custom mapping from JSON to EDM XML the only way to ingest an index definition from Azure Cognitive Search?

Not able to add custom query strings to the HTTP request from a message hook.  See [message creation code](https://gist.github.com/MatthewDavidCampbell/d81461900f7631a2ef44af1787d0c7bf) (gist) where mandatory Azure Search api version is added to the query strings plus headers get an authorization key.  The api-version is not being propagated in a [sample test case](https://gist.github.com/MatthewDavidCampbell/5f392ea1266fe0f55798816758114a63) (gist).

**OBS**: `.AddQueryOption` in the Linq expression fixes the api-version problem.

Comment: Can you share a code sample of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Using AddQueryOption("api-version", "2021-04-30-Preview") fixes the api-version problem with the Linq expression.

Comment: `Is a custom mapping from JSON to EDM XML the only way to ingest an index definition from Azure Cognitive Search?`: 

Have you tried accessing the $metadata endpoint at `GET {{host}}/indexes/{{index}}/$metadata?api-version=2020-06-30` ? That should return the CSDL xml document.

Comment: @giulianob Nice.  No major difference between version 2021-04-30-Preview and 2020-06-30 except query result metadata.  No problems imports.  Thanks

Comment: @giulianob Can you lift your comment into an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSDL xml document can be found in the `$metadata` endpoint by calling GET `{{host}}/indexes/{{index}}/$metadata?api-version=2020-06-30`