# Set schema name when getting EDM model from Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: c#, rest, odata, azure-cognitive-search

Getting the EDM model for a specific index in xml from Azure Cognitive Search:

```
https://(search endpoint)//indexes//(index name)//$metadata?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview
```

The identifiers for the schema containing the entity + complex types is **search** == schema name, **document** == entity name, **documentFields** == complex type, and container references to the entities are prefixed with (guess what) **search**.

Anyway to force custom schema identifiers?  For example if my index is named **Actor** then the logical schema name would be **Actor**.  Why?  It might be useful to merge 2 or more index schemas.  Also Azure Search doesn't seem to have an endpoint that yields an EDM model for all indexes.  Something like:

```
https://(search endpoint)//indexes//$metadata?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview
```

Another thing I would love to read is the Microsoft documentation of the **$metadata** path in their REST endpoints.  Can't find anything.  @giulianob gave me sample path on the [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248872/odata-client-message-creation-hook-when-using-azure-cognitive-search).

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway to force custom schema identifiers?

Not at the moment. These names are constants given by the OData service and are not user defined.

> Also Azure Search doesn't seem to have an endpoint that yields an EDM model for all indexes.

That's correct. Azure Cognitive Search treats each index as a separate OData service so it's not possible to get a definition for all indexes.